# How to pass cropped image to another activity from Firebase (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

Issue: I would like the user to be able to upload an image from the gallery, crop it, and then I would like this image to pass to the imageview of another activity.

- In Activity1, the user can upload a profile picture to Circle ImageView.
- This uploaded picture should then pass to the Circle ImageView of another activity (Personal_Wall.class).
- I have tried with different solutions from the internet and nothing seems to be working. Common errors usually result in a crash of the App.
- For any solutions, please also tell me where it should go in the code.
  -Thanks so much!

Activity1:

```
    public class Add_Info_After_Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText FirstName;
        private EditText LastName;
        private Button RegisterInfoButton;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private DatabaseReference UsersReference;
        private CircleImageView ProfileImage;
        private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        String currentUserID;
        final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
        private Uri uri;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__info__after__registration);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            //this is referring to storing username information in firebase//
            UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);        //this is referring to storing username information in firebase//
            FirstName = findViewById(R.id.add_info_first_name);
            LastName =  findViewById(R.id.add_info_last_name);
            RegisterInfoButton = findViewById(R.id.register_submit_button);
            ProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

            //Text Watcher For First Name//
            FirstName.addTextChangedListener(registerTextWatcher);
            LastName.addTextChangedListener(registerTextWatcher);
            //Text Watcher For First Name//

            RegisterInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SaveAccountSetupInformation();
                }
            });

            ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*"); //this will only choose images from the gallery and not videos, etc...//
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
                }
            });

            UsersReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                        {
                            String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_place_holder).into(ProfileImage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Please select profile image first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        //Textwatcher method//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private TextWatcher registerTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String firstnameinput = FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                String lastnameinput = LastName.getText().toString().trim();
                LastName.setError("Please Enter Name");
                FirstName.setError("Please Enter Name");

                //This says when the submit button is clicked, it will disable if the firstname or last name is empty//
                RegisterInfoButton.setEnabled(!firstnameinput.isEmpty() && !lastnameinput.isEmpty());
                //This says when the submit button is clicked, it will disable if the firstname or last name is empty//

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if( FirstName.getText().length()>0)
                {
                    FirstName.setError(null);
                }

                if( LastName.getText().length()>0)
                {
                    LastName.setError(null);
                }
            }
        };
        //Textwatcher method/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();

                CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .start(this);
            }

            // when pressing the crop button//
            if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                    StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                    filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                                Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Image has been added sucessfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Task<Uri> result = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                                result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                                        UsersReference.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, Add_Info_After_Registration.class); //Change if neededCHECK THIS LATER THIS MAY BE THE REASON WHY THE CODE REFRESHES AFTER YOU CHOOSE A PICTURE
                                                            startActivity(selfIntent);

                                                            Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Image has been stored...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        } else {
                                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                            Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Error: Image did not upload. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveAccountSetupInformation()
        {
            String firstname = FirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastname = LastName.getText().toString();

             //Below is the error message if the user does not enter a first name or last name.
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname))
            {
                FirstName.setError("Input is required!");

            }
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
            {
                LastName.setError("Input is required!");

                //Above is the error message if the user does not enter a first name or last name.
            }
            else
            {
                HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
                userMap.put("firstname", firstname);
                userMap.put("lastname", lastname);
                UsersReference.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "your Account is created Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message =  task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, "Error Occurred: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private void SendUserToMainActivity()
        {
            Intent setupIntent = new Intent(Add_Info_After_Registration.this, MainActivity.class);
            setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(setupIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Activity 2:

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

    public class Personal_Wall extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private DrawerLayout drawer;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private Uri uri;
        String currentUserID;
        private DatabaseReference UsersReference;
        private CircleImageView profile_image;
        private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        Intent intent;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal__wall);

    //Bringing in Database Stuff//
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
            UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);

    //Bringing in Database Stuff//
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //this tells our system to actually use the toolbar as the actionbar.

            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_place_holder);
            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.log_out:
                    LogOut();
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        private void LogOut() {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendToLogin();
        }

        private void sendToLogin() {

            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Personal_Wall.this, Login_Activity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

What I have tried:

I have used the following as found from related threads.

However, after implementing this code, I was still unable to pass the image.

```
//For first Activity//
Intent i = new Intent(this, Personal_Wall.class);
Bitmap b; // your bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
i.putExtra("profileimage", bs.toByteArray());
startActivity(i);

//For Second Activity//
if(getIntent().hasExtra("profileimage")) {
    ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("profileimage"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
    previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
```

}

If this is still the correct code for what I need, can you please let me know where it should go in my code. The reason for my error could me a result of me putting this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Well since you have the downloaded uri, why not just pass the string instead of the bitmap:

Activity 1:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, personal_wall.class);
                        intent.putExtra("image", downloadurl.tostring());
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            String img= intent.getExtras().getString("image");

    then use a library like glide to set the img url:

    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(img).into(imgHolder);
```

Glide is really helpful. Plus using strings will make your life easier if you're planning on passing bitmaps back and fouth since you have to make sure it doesn't exceeed the parceil size or whatever it's called. Lot's o' crashing. I'm learning the hard way too. lol